# AngularJS, best way to create little slider above tabs in menu

Tags: jquery, angularjs, slider, directive

I want to create a little tile above the active tab of a menu on top of the page.
There are three tabs like:

---

Menu | Help | About

This tile slides to the tab - that is, hovered - and stays there if the tab is clicked.

Now I tried to create my own directive, in which I do dom manipulations via selectors and the hover method. In the function, I just change the width and position (left) of the tile. It works fine with normal elements, but when I try to call the function on my menu elements (which are created through ng-repeat, in contrast to others) it just doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong, and what does this have to do with ng-repeat?

I would be very thankful for every idea and help.

Maybe someone can give me a completely different attempt :)

Comment: For some reason I read 'spider' instead of 'slider' and this question really made me think:)

Comment: In general, when posting questions where you've written some code and it doesn't do what you want it to, it is extremely helpful if you *post* that code (more specifically, a minimal amount of code that still reproduces the same issue you're trying solve.)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i wanted to get a better approach than my code. I'm not a angular pro, so i thought someone can tell me how to implement such a "wdiget".

Answer (score 0):

Made it by myself...
I understand, that the question is badly posed, but I thought that someone can give me advice about how to realize something like that in common.

Well, now I created a directive that just binds a click and hover listening function to the menu-tabs. That way, I get the position and width information of each tab and can slide the tile above them correctly.

Thanks for your help!